# Range referencing 2 variables for Column and Row

Tags: excel, vba, variables, range, long-integer

I often use code that references a Long that represents the last row of my data, such as "LastrowProjectList" shown below.

In this instance I also have a Long to replace Column H, in both instances where H is used in Range("H1:H"...

The Long to replace H is named "ProjectColumn". How do I re-write this such that H is replaced with "ProjectColumn"?

```
For Each ThisCellinProjectList In Sheets("VBA_Data").Range("H1:H" & LastrowProjectList)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
For Each ThisCellinProjectList In Sheets("VBA_Data").Range(Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(1, ProjectColumn), Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(LastrowProjectList, ProjectColumn))
```

or

```
With Sheets("VBA_Data")
    For Each ThisCellinProjectList In .Range(.Cells(1, ProjectColumn), .Cells(LastrowProjectList, ProjectColumn))
    'rest code here
    Next ThisCellinProjectList
End With
```

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, it was just one variable too much for me to handle with my limited understanding! Thanks (First code worked, didn;t try the second)

Comment: @pwm2017 - By using `With...End With`, you can perform a series of statements on a specified object without specifying the name of the object multiple times as `Sheets("VBA_Data")` is repeated 3 times in `For` loop. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/with-end-with-statement) for details.